# Openvbx install error : An application error occurred in STEP 3

Tags: twilio

I have tried vbx instalation in local and cpanel but I got the error(An application error occurred). Error in In Step : 3

My Xamp Configuration :

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP 
Server type: MySQL 
Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) 
Protocol version: 10 
User: root@localhost 
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**I got following error when install by using xampl server in my local system:**

[image]

[image]

**I have tried cpanel server also, but that not help.**

**Cpanel Error:**

[image]